# Sklearn tfidf vectorize returns different shape after fit_transform()

Tags: python, scikit-learn, feature-extraction, tfidf

I'm new to ML and trying out [basic samples](https://github.com/yashhy/sklearn-kick-start) using sklearn. I have achieved converting text (single dimension) to numbers using TF-IDF and got the [predictions correct](https://github.com/yashhy/sklearn-kick-start/tree/master/spam-or-not/test-ur-sentence).

Now I have a different [use-case](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/yashhy/sklearn-kick-start/master/tfidf-2d-matrix/adult.data) to predict ***Work Hours*** based on ***Marital-Status*** and ***Relationship Status*** so my training data is now two dimension.

I have `DataFrame` total of `24420 rows * 2 columns` of shape --> `(24420, 2)`

After this `DataFrame` is been passed to `TfidfVectorizer.fit_transform()` function it turns to shape --> `(2, 3)` Not sure why!

And while training `mnb.fit(x_train_tf, y_train)` it returns an error

> ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [2, 24420]

You could see the initial `DataFrame` shape of `24420*2` it transposed to `2*24420`

All code is up [here](https://github.com/yashhy/sklearn-kick-start/blob/f3e5c5f1e1fcabe6ac80a2dbb21b84b93143c4d0/tfidf-2d-matrix/tfidf_vectorize_2d.py).

**Questions:**

1. Why after `fit_transform()` the shape changes to `(2,3)` what happened to `(24420,2)` data? What does this denotes?
2. Why does the `ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples [2, 24420]` occurs?
3. Why initial `DataFrame` shape changed to `2*24420`?

What is wrong with the implementation?

Answer (score 3):

What is wrong with your implementation is that you are passing a dataframe directly to tfidf vectorizer. If you check your data, it would look like this -

```
>>> x_train_tf.toarray()
array([[ 0.70710678,  0.        ,  0.70710678],
       [ 0.        ,  1.        ,  0.        ]])
```

If you check what features you are getting, you will see -

```
>>> tfidf.get_feature_names()
[u'marital', u'relationship', u'status']
```

What's happening is, while passing dataframe, the **TfidfVectorizer** is only taking the column names and converting them into numeric form.

I don't think you need to use **tfidf** here. As far as I understand, your data is categorical text, so use `pandas.get_dummies()` instead of tfidf. This will convert your categorical data to numeric form which you can use for modelling.

```
>>> pd.get_dummies(x_train.iloc[:10,])
       marital-status_Divorced  marital-status_Married-civ-spouse  marital-status_Never-married  marital-status_Widowed  relationship_Husband  relationship_Not-in-family  relationship_Own-child  relationship_Unmarried 
1521                   1                          0                              0                        0                       0                            1                         0                        0 
2274                   0                          1                              0                        0                       1                            0                         0                        0 
20209                  0                          1                              0                        0                       1                            0                         0                        0 
5529                   0                          1                              0                        0                       1                            0                         0                        0 
27639                  0                          1                              0                        0                       1                            0                         0                        0 
26670                  0                          0                              1                        0                       0                            1                         0                        0 
16635                  0                          0                              0                        1                       0                            0                         0                        1 
30824                  0                          0                              1                        0                       0                            1                         0                        0 
15181                  0                          0                              1                        0                       0                            0                         1                        0 
9119                   1                          0                              0                        0                       0                            0                         1                        0
```

Here, for demo purpose, I have taken only 10 rows.

Comment: thanks, my actual case includes data which are NOT categorical and have over 6 lakhs records. So I have to use TF-IDF with two column data. Do you know how to solve that?

Comment: @Ankit Seth I have a dataset which contains text data and I am getting a similar error. After calling `fit_transform` the resulting sparse matrix has size = 1.

Comment: @spectre Check what `fit_transform` is doing to your data. I can't help unless I have data and code of what you are doing and what you want to do.

Comment: @AnkitSeth Here is the link to my question    https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/100429/sparse-matrix-after-vectorization-giving-size-1

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem. What I was doing was this: I loaded a pretrained tfidf vectorizer. And on the new data to be predicted, I called `vectorizer.fit_transform()` and I got similar error.

What solved the issue was calling `vectorizer.transform()`. It is because, `fit_transform()` will fit the current data in the model, which is not what we are seeking because vectorizer has already been fitted. We just need to transform the new data to model which has been created. So, calling `vectorizer.transform()` did the work.

Comment: But you have to fit the transform on the train set first. If you directly call `transform` you will get an error saying that the tfidf vectorizer is not fitted.